# Adjoint representation of Sl(2,C)

Tags: lie-algebras

What is the adjoint representation of Sl(2,C). Can anyone help explain this please?

Comment: Can you describe what you already understand about it?

Comment: Yes, in general the adjoint representation is a map ad: L ----> Der(L), x--->adx. So in this case would it just be a 2x2 matrix of some kind? @Vincent oh and the trace of the matrix x must be =1 i believe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From your comment I understand that you are talking about the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}(2, \mathbb{C})$ not the group $SL(2, \mathbb{C})$.

Let's zoom out a bit and talk about Lie algebra representations in general.

Lie algebra representations involve (obviously) a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, but equally importantly a vector space $V$.

The third and final ingredient is a map $\phi \colon \mathfrak{g} \to End(V)$, where the latter is the space of all linear maps from $V$ to itself (equivalently: the space of all $n \times n$-matrices, with $n = \dim V$), viewed as a Lie algebra with bracket $[A, B] = AB - BA$.

So the map $\phi$ assigns to each element $X \in \mathfrak{g}$ a matrix (or linear map, depending on your perspective). This is in line with your comment.

Also in line with your comment we can say that in the special case of *adjoint* representations the map $\phi$ is called 'ad'. But before we can say what *is* this map we must first answer the more important question: *what is the space $V$?*

This is the important part: the vector space $V$ on which the Lie algebra acts is the lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ itself! We forget some of its structure, and just see it as a vector space.

So in the case of $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{sl}(2, \mathbb{C})$ we have that the representation space $V$ is three dimensional and hence for each $X \in \mathfrak{sl}(2, \mathbb{C})$ the corresponding matrix $ad(X)$ is a three-by-three (not two by two) matrix!

However, in this case things are a bit easier if you think about $ad(X)$ not so much as a matrix but more as a linear transformation, i.e. a linear map sending elements of the vector space $\mathfrak{g}$ to elements of the vector space $\mathfrak{g}$. In this setting the map $ad(X)$ (for any Lie algebra, not just $\mathfrak{sl}(2, \mathbb{C})$) is easily described:

> $ad(X)$ is the map that takes an element $Y$ and sends it to the element $[X, Y]$

It is a nice exercise to compute the corresponding matrix with respect to a vector space basis of $\mathfrak{g}$. Elements of $\mathfrak{g}$ now appear in two ways: as vectors in the representation space $V$ (which just happens to be $\mathfrak{g}$ itself), and as matrices *acting* on that space (their images under ad).

For instance, if I take the standard basis of $\mathfrak{sl}(2, \mathbb{C})$ where $E$ is the two-by-two matrix with a 1 in the top right corner, and otherwise zeroes, $F$ is its transpose, and $H$ is the diagonal matrix with 1 in the top left and -1 in the lower right corner then, viewed as an element of the space $V$ the element $E$ looks like the vector $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

The element $ad(E)$ on the other hand looks like $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & - 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

It is easy to see that if you multiply matrix $ad(E)$ with vector $E$ you get the zero-vector. This is correct because the outcome should be the vector corresponding to $[E, E]$, which is zero. Similarly since $[E, F] = H$ we know that $ad(E)$ maps $F$ to $H$ and hence that multiplying the matrix $ad(E)$ given above with the vector $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ we will get the vector $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ corresponding to $H$ in the $\{E, F, H\}$ basis.

See if you can compute the matrices corresponding to $ad(F)$ and $ad(H)$ yourself!

Comment: sl2 has the following "axioms": $[EF] = H, [EH]=-2E,[FH]=2F$.

i have something else for $ad(E)$: $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

for $ad(F)$: $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & +2 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

and finally $ad(H)$: $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

this sort of feels wrong?

my thoughts were (hand-wavy):

$E \mapsto e_1$ (then represent $[EF] = H$, then $e_1 \mapsto e_3$ and thats what is put into the matrix for $ad_E(F)$?) $F \mapsto e_2$ and $H \mapsto e_3$

thanks!

Comment: Hi, as you say: $[E, H] = -2E$. So the map $ad(E)$ sends vector $H$ (also known as $e_3$) to -2 times vector $E$, also known as -2 times $e_1$. Now for *any* matrix $A$ the third column of $A$ equals the vector $Ae_3$ written out in the standard basis. So in our case where $A = ad(E)$ and hence $Ae_3 = -2e_1$ we get that the third column of $ad(E)$ must read (from top to bottom): -2, 0, 0. So there is a minus sign missing in your $ad(E)$. Your $ad(F)$ and $ad(H)$ are correct.

Comment: Now you can check that with my $ad(E)$ and your $ad(F)$ and $ad(H)$ we do indeed get $[ad(E), ad(F)] = ad(H)$, $[ad(H), ad(E)] = 2ad(E)$, $[ad(H), ad(F)] = -2ad(F)$. Where [ ] is defined by [A, B] = AB - BA, the ordinary Lie bracket for 3x3-matrices

Comment: Ahh yeah is see it now! indeed $ad(E)$ has -2 instead of my 2.
thanks for replying that quickly.